# Page translate using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hey guyzz can any one plz help me,i want to translate my webpage into another language using angular js but my question is,do angularjs-translate translates my page automatically or i need to create all my json files related to each language and for each language each word must be translated.For example i want to translate website into spanish then all my words present into website must be translated into spanish and then add to json and then need to use that json for translation.Can't i translate my page directly into any other language using angular-translate.Plzz help me

Comment: you must have all text into json files and load the corresponding language using angular-translate. I don't know any other magic way for having different languages translated on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here:

https://angular-translate.github.io/

You must have the translate object somewhere. (usually .json flie)